# Evitar que se acumulen las pestañas en sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

En sublime text se me acumulan las pestaañs y se tieen que visualizar con una flecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se configura sublime para que no se oculten las pestañas?¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si acaso, los tabs no desaparecen del todo y puedes usar el scroll para moverte entre ellos (no hace falta usar la flecha).

Aún así hay otra alternativa, ve a las preferencias y añade esto: `"enable_tab_scrolling": false,`

Comment: gracias ;) .........